# setting checkbox to check Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-col="1" name="eighth-slot" data-ng-model="scope.friends.calendar[0][8]" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

the first [0] is the day of the week and the second [8] indicates a 2hr time slot and returns true/false indicating if they are free on that day during that particular time slot.

I figure binding the model to the input is the first thing but how do I make it checked if the the last parameter is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to say `scope.friends.calendar[0][8]` as `scope` is
assumed to be receiver in the template.  so just `friends.calendar[0][8]` is fine.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.friends = {calendar: [[]]};
  $scope.friends.calendar[0][8] = true;
}
```

for instance, would make the checkbox checked.